# Как можно оптимизировать метод String getType(Object o)?

Tags: java, задание-на-собеседовании

Не так давно у меня было собеседование в компанию Luxoft. И был задан такой вопрос - "На код ревью к вам приходит метод String getType(Object obj). Также известно, что со временем этот метод нужно будет расширять, чтобы он работал с новыми типами. Чтобы вы в этом методе могли улучшить?". Подскажите если какое то более компактное или универсальное решение реализации этого метода? Вот код метода:

```
public String getType(Object obj) {       
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        return "String";
    }
    if (obj instanceof List) {
        return "List";
    }
    if (obj instanceof ArrayList) {
        return "ArrayList";
    }
    if (obj instanceof Number) {
        return "Number";
    }        
    return "";
}
```

Comment: С ходу видно что если передать в качестве параметра объект типа ArrayList, то вернет значение "List", т.е.  условие  if (obj instanceof ArrayList) ни когда не сработает. Я так думаю это был вопрос с подковыркой, которую Вам надо было увидеть.

Answer (score 10):

Любой тип будет поддерживаться этим методом

```
public String getType(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Object = null");
    }
    return o.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

Comment: Небольшая правка: любой [неанонимный](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()) тип

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это не подходит. Дело в том что если передать в метод List list = new LinkedList(); то Ваша реализация вернёт 'LinkedList', а нужно чтобы возвращалось 'List'.

Comment: @IgorUssov вам в комментарии уже отметили, что для ArrayList тоже List вернется, может вы не правильно запомнили задание или код?

Comment: @IronVklf, не знаю даже как сделать

Answer (score 5):

предложу такую модификацию способа @Flippy

```
public String getType(Object o) {
    if (o == null) 
       return null;
    Class<?> clazz=o.getClass();
    Class<?>[] interfaces=clazz.getInterfaces();
    String interfaceName=null; 
    int shortestLength=Integer.MAX_INT;
    //ищем интерфейс с самым коротким именем
    for(Class<?> interfaze:interfaces) {
       if(interfaze.getSimpleName().length() < shortestName) {
          interfaceName=interfaze.getSimpleName();
          shortestName=interfaze.getSimpleName().length();
       }
    }
    if(interfaceName==null)
       return clazz.getSimpleName();
    return interfaceName();
}
```

Comment: Прикольно. Но я бы поискал не самое короткое имя, а то, которое является подстрокой имени класса. Хотя, возможно, логично брать самое первое, потому что программисты обычно самое важное пишут в начале. Или такая схема не прокатит?

Comment: Поправка: `interface` нельзя использовать как название переменной ибо это одно и ключевых слов синтаксиса

Answer (score 4):

> Также известно, что со временем этот метод нужно будет расширять, чтобы он работал с новыми типами.

Исходя из этого условия, я предполагаю, что метод на данный момент работает только с ограниченными типами данных:

```
    private static final Map<Class, String> SUPPORTED_TYPES = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        SUPPORTED_TYPES.put(List.class, "List");
        SUPPORTED_TYPES.put(ArrayList.class, "ArrayList");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(getType(new ArrayList<>()));
        System.out.println(getType(new LinkedList<>()));
    }

    public static String getType(Object obj) {
        String rez = SUPPORTED_TYPES.get(obj.getClass());
        if (rez == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class " + obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + " does not supported");
        }
        return rez;
    }
```

Вместо добавления кода в метод, новый тип будет добавляться в мапу. Мапу можно заполнять из внешних источников (например, из базы, пропертей или конфигурационного файла)